# Find the irreducible components of the affine variety $V(x_1-x_2 x_3,x_1 x_3-x_2^2)$ in $A_C^3$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Find the irreducible components of the affine variety $V(x_1-x_2 x_3,x_1 x_3-x_2^2)$ in $A_C^3$.

I found that this variety can be written as $\{(t^3,t^2,t):t\in C\}\cup \{(0,0,x_3)\}$. The second part is irreducible.

For the first part, I know that I should define a homomorphism $\phi: C[x_1,x_2,x_3]\rightarrow C[t]$ such that $\phi(x_1)=t^3, \phi(x_2)=t^2, \phi(x^3 )=t$.

My questions are:

1. Is it true that $\ker{\phi}=I(V)$?
2. Is it true that image of $\phi$ is isomorphic to $C[t]$?

If those are true, then $I(V)$ is prime, so $V$ is irreducible.

My next question is kind of unrelated.

3. IF for some other variety $U=\{(t^2,t^3,t^6):t\in C\}$, the image is not isomorphic to $C[t]$ any more. Is it still an integral domain so that $I$ is prime and hence $V(I)$ is irreducible?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: the following link might be helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1020945/ideals-algebraic-set

Comment: regarding your last question: the image is not isomorphic to $\mathbb C[t],$ but it's a subring of $\mathbb C[t]$ and hence an integral domain. so the kernel will be a prime ideal.

Comment: @Krish It's very helpful! Thank you very much!